# Asp.net MVC (Data unable updated)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The database is no working but no error come out, can someone explain to me what I did wrong. I want to update the column after the validation done.

```
public ActionResult Autherize(MoIS.Models.medicalassistant maModel)
{
    using (DBModels dBModel = new DBModels())
    {
        var maDetails = dBModel.medicalassistants.Where(x => x.Username == maModel.Username && x.Password == maModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        if (maDetails == null)
        {
            maModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password.";
            return View("Index", maModel);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                medicalassistant m = dBModel.medicalassistants.First(i => i.MaID == maDetails.MaID);
                m.Name = "ali";
                dBModel.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Updated");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            }
            Session["maID"] = maDetails.MaID;
            Session["username"] = maDetails.Username;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dbmodel is your dbcontext? Share your dbmodel

Comment: What you mean by  "not working" ? What is your expected behavior ? Have you tried putting breakpoints in your code and verify it is executing as expected ?

Comment: Execute no problem, no error

Comment: Do you get the correct behaviour if you purposely input the wrong username and password? When you do have the correct username and password, you want to change the m.Name to "ali" is that all? Is the database column actually called "Name"? What happens if you change the column name to something less risky, like "FullName"?